# Installing Pillow requirements on debian Jessie

Tags: debian, docker, apt, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install Pillow and requirements in a Docker container based on the official images which I believe use Debian Jessie, but some of the installation packages I would install on Ubuntu aren't available in Debian it seems.

In particular, they are libwebp-dev, tcl8.6-dev, tk8.6-dev, python-tk

If I search for these online I do find some listed. eg, https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libwebp-dev

But installing with apt doesn't work (`Unable to locate package libwebp-dev`) and searching with apt-cache doesn't show anything.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Did you first do `apt-get update `